# Java SWT: read-only preview of existing composites

Tags: java, swt, screenshot, e4

We have got a number of `Composite`s (let's say around 10), which shall all be displayed in a kind of overview with the following properties:

- read-only
- smaller than the original

One way would be to take a screenshot of each composite and then display the pictures.

Do you know of any simpler method to do this?